# Why are constraint forces and gradient of constraint functions perpendicular?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

My question is about the general relationship between the constraint functions and the constraint forces, but I found it easier to explain my problem over the example of a double pendulum:

Consider a double pendulum with the generalized coordinates

[image: double pendulum]

The set of constraint functions is:
$$f=
\begin{pmatrix} 
l_1-\text{const.}_1\\ 
l_2-\text{const.}_2\\
\end{pmatrix}
=0$$

Since $f=0$ describes the level curve $N_0(f)$, it describes a submanifold in the configuration space, the generalized coordinates of phase space
Since this is a level curve, $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to the manifold embedded in the configuration space
However, the constraint *forces* act on the physical plane of motion, which is a submanifold in $3d$ space
Therefore, I don't understand how we can say that $\nabla f\| F_\text{constraint}$ in the Lagrangian mechanics, since they act on manifolds embedded in different spaces

Comment: The example you have chosen to study this is very complicated. It is much easier if you tried to consider a particle being constrained to move along the surface of a sphere / along a circle. The gradient of the constraint function concept that you are trying to learn, here, is really the concept of the method of Lagrange's undetermined multipliers. You might be able to find a nice treatment of the subject elsewhere, that will bring much more clarity than studying this system.

Comment: The short answer is because by definition constraint forces do no work. Thus they need to act in a perpendicular fashion to the directions of possible motion.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is about the general relationship between the constraint functions and the constraint forces

starting with the position vectors to the masses  $~\vec P_1~,\vec P_2~$

$$\vec P_1=\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1 \\
  y_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\quad,
\vec P_2=\begin{bmatrix}
  x_2 \\
  y_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
the constraint equations are

$$f_{c1}=\vec P_1\cdot\vec P_1-l_1^2=0\\
f_{c2}=\left(\vec P_2-\vec P_1\right)\cdot \left(\vec P_2-\vec P_1\right)-l_2^2=0$$

from here you obtain the  constraint forces $~\vec F_c~$

$$\vec F_c=\underbrace{\mathbf C_c^T}_{4\times 2}\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \lambda_1 \\
  \lambda_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $~\lambda_i~$ are generalized constraint forces and

$$~\mathbf C_c=\frac {\partial \vec f}{\partial \vec P}\quad,
\vec f=\begin{bmatrix}
  \vec{f}_{c1} \\
   \vec{f}_{c2} \\
\end{bmatrix}\quad,\vec P=\begin{bmatrix}
  \vec{P}_{1} \\
   \vec{P}_{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

---

$$\mathbf C_c=\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} x_{{1}}&y_{{2}}&0&0\\  -
x_{{2}}+x_{{1}}&0&x_{{2}}-x_{{1}}&0\end {array} \right]
$$